# Leaflet, create clickable lines between markers

Tags: vue.js, leaflet

I'm new to leaflet.  I am showing a network map (think of routers and such) plotted on the leaflet map using markers.  I can click on the markers (network elements) and present info about the network element that was clicked on.

I now want to show the edges between the network elements.  I would like to create an edge between an A and Z network element (I already know the markers for the A and Z).  I would also like to be able to click on an edge and present info about that edge.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Use ```L.polyline``` to create a polyline object given an array of geographical points and adds it to the map.